# Signature enquiries

Tags: email

I would like to know when I attach my signature in my email. Which type of regards I should choose?

> Best Regards,
>  Drew, Lim Chee Lim
>
> Best Regards,
>  Drew, Lim C. L.
>
> Best Regards,
>  Lim C. L

Which one is more appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Last/family name, First/given name] formulation is never used in English in this context.

Here are the possibilities:

> Best Regards,
>
> John Smith

or

> Best Regards,
>
> John H. Smith

or

> Best Regards,
>
> J. Howard Smith

or

> Best Regards,
>
> Howard Smith

or

> Best Regards,
>
> Howard

or

> Best Regards,
>
> John

The proper choice is based on (1) how you want to be addressed and (2) how you want to present yourself.  The single name form is not helpful when emailing strangers if you will ever want them to learn your last name.  It is the most common form, however, when manually typing a closing line to an email to people you already know.  Choice of including middle initials can be helpful to distinguish yourself from others that might have a similar name (John Smith would be quite common in English) but is a matter of personal style.  It would be quite rare to spell out your full name ("John Howard Smith") unless you are in the habit of being called by multiple names in conversation e.g., "John Howard".  This is, however, unusual.

In the general case, you should use (1) the name you are called in conversation, followed by (2) your last name.  Middle initials should be included if you are likely to be confused with others with the same or a similar name.

Comment: The OP clearly has a Chinese name, so it is most confusing when you insist on using the term 'last name'. (What's wrong with 'surname'.) In many Asian countries, e.g. Chinese & Japanese, the family name goes first. I also think you are pushing your luck in telling Chinese people how to write their names. My wife is of Chinese descent, and like many Chinese outside China adopts a western Christian name.    So in everyday life she uses the English format of Christian name, surname. But when formally using her Chinese name it is Surname, Given name (usually hyphenated) as in 'Mao Tse-Tung'.

Comment: @WS2  Surname is as ethnocentric as last name.  Its traditional opposite is 'Christian name', not first name.  Icelanders don't even have 'surnames', they have patronymics; and Spaniards have two surnames from both sides of the family.  Basically if a foreign language speaker doesn't learn the English concept of first name and last name they will be in trouble even if they don't use it themselves.

Comment: @Merk There are enough Asian people living in English-speaking countries to make it quite ridiculous to use an expression like 'last name'.  'Surname' or 'family name' are perfectly clear. And you don't have to use 'Christian name' if you are a Hindu or atheist, you can use 'given name'.

Comment: @WS2 Well, you'll have to pass a law about that somewhere then, because even in these globalizing times, Google ngrams has 'last name' about to overtake 'surname', with 'first name' way more popular than 'given name.'  I'll also note that simply using a different word doesn't automatically make anyone more culturally literate, and that using 'first name'/'last name' is not chauvinistic if the people that use it take it to be context- and culture-relative.

Comment: @Mark But if I was Chinese and my name was Mao Tse-Tung, and the stupid form asked for my 'last name', what would I write?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from your examples that you have a given personal name of "Chee Lim", a family name of "Lim", prefer family name first ordering when using your real name, and use "Drew" as a nickname among anglophones.

I'd suggest writing your family name in all capitals or smallcaps, while sticking to your preferred ordering.

> LIM Chee Lim

As for the nickname, I'd suggest putting it in parentheses after your name.

> LIM Chee Lim (Drew)

or

> LIM Chee Lim (Drew LIM)

With anglophone names there's a convention of putting nicknames in the middle surrounded by double quotes.  For instance I often go by "Hai-Etlik" online, so if I wanted to indicate that as part of my name I might write:

> Kevin "Hai-Etlik" SMITH

However, I don't think it's readily adaptable to other name structures without causing more confusion than it resolves.